# How is the ">" operator implemented (on 32-bit integers)?

Tags: x86, compiler-construction, integer, language-agnostic, comparison

Let's say that the environment is x86.

How do compilers compile the ">" operator on 32-bit integers. Logically, I mean. Without any knowledge of Assembly.

Let's say that the high level language code is:

```c
int32 x, y;
x = 123;
y = 456;
bool z;
z = x > y;
```

What does the compiler do for evaluating the expression `x > y`?

Does it perform something like (assuming that x and y are positive integers):

```c
w = sign_of(x - y);
if (w == 0)
   // expression is 'false'
else if (w == 1)
   // expression is 'true'
else
   // expression is 'false'
```

Is there any reference for such information?

Comment: In the case of x86, I'm pretty sure there is a CPU instruction that does this, and the compiler will just use that directly. How the CPU implements it is probably more to do with bit arithmetic than any logical comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure integer comparisons are implemented at the CPU level. At that level, you are usually looking at something like the the following logic:

```
x > y if y - x < 0
```

This looks like a recursive definition, but isn't since the second half can be determined by looking at the sign bit of the result.

To expand on this slightly, from a description of [the `CMP` instruction in x86](http://siyobik.info/index.php?module=x86&id=35) which is what the compiler would compile a `>` operator to, but maps more directly to the `<=>` operator available in some languages.

> Compares the first source operand with the second source operand and sets the status flags in the EFLAGS register according to the results. The comparison is performed by subtracting the second operand from the first operand and then setting the status flags in the same manner as the SUB instruction.

[The reference on SUB.](http://siyobik.info/index.php?module=x86&id=308)

After the CMP instruction, the compiler then needs to do one or more conditional instructions, but this is how the actual comparison works.

Comment: many errors here. Your definition does not looks recursive, it looks like a tautology. to change `x > y` to `y - x < 0` is just moving x from one side of the inequality to the other, always true. And no **CMP does not map directly to `<=>` at all**. To get the equivalent of `<=>` you must have a processor where cmp computes several bits at once: underflow and equality to zero (for <=> returning -1, 0, 1) or perform the real substraction and has branching instruction depending on sign and zero. That probably explains why C does not have <=> as it does not map well to most assemblers.

Comment: @kriss: Of course it is a tautology: if it wasn't, then we wouldn't be able to use it as the basis for `CMP`! As for the rest, that is the reason I used the wording 'more directly' instead of 'directly'. It doesn't map directly, but `CMP` is a heck of a lot closer to `<=>` than to simply `>`.

Comment: basically CMP returns a boolean : one bit (even if quite often several booleans at once in a flag register) this boolean will usually be used by branching instruction later. As ">" returns a boolean, but not <=> that returns either three values, either an integer depending on languages, this instruction is clearly very, very different. It's result is not even of the same logical type! What is true is that some old assembler instructions sets does not allow for storing CMP result and the compiled program has to introduce a conditional jump to store it and that is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Well, logically it's *something* like that.  The thing is that "compare two integers" is generally a primitive operation on almost any machine, so from the standpoint of the machine if just does a compare.  The exact details differ from architecture to architecture, but in general you'd have something like a CMP instruction that leaves a condition code or other such control signal for "less than" "equal" and "greater than".  So the generated code would be something like

```
         LD A, X    ; value of x into register A
         LD B, y    ;
         CMP        ; compare reg A with reg B
```

at which point the result code has the answer.  If you want to *store* the result, then you use the sort of conditional you have --

```
         JMPGE @FALSE ; goto label FALSE if >=
         STO   Z, 0x1 ; put a hex 1 into location Z
         JMP   @END   ; jump to the end
FALSE:   STO   Z, 0x0
END:
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically `(y - x) & INT32_SIGN_BIT` for microcode.

64-bit comparisons on 32-bit architectures tend to be more interesting as the 64-bit sign bit may not be recognized as a true value and you have to force the check, i.e. `((y - x) & INT64_SIGN_BIT) != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good reference:

http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_6/CH06-2.html#HEADING2-244

Answer (score 0):

All comparisons in x86 (and any architectures that use [flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register)) are implemented by doing a temporary subtraction and then set some flags depending on the result. The CPU can then use those flags to decide whether to jump on any comparisons such as >, >=, =, <=, <

[image: x86 flag regsiter]

For example to check if two values equal, it'll check if their difference is zero (ZF = 1). To check if a < b (unsigned) then it'll check if a - b needs a borrow (i.e. CF = 1). Below are some comparing conditions on x86:

```
JE      Jump if equal                           ZF = 1
JZ      Jump if zero

JNE     Jump if not equal                       ZF = 0
JNZ     Jump if not zero

JB      Jump if below               unsigned    CF = 1 
JNAE    Jump if not above or equal
JC      Jump if carry

JNB     Jump if not below           unsigned    CF = 0 
JAE     Jump if above or equal
JNC     Jump if not carry

JBE     Jump if below or equal      unsigned    CF = 1 or ZF = 1
JNA     Jump if not above

JA      Jump if above               unsigned    CF = 0 and ZF = 0
JNBE    Jump if not below or equal
```

You can all of see them [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html)

Some architectures (such as MIPS) don't use flags but rather set a register to some specific value based on the comparison result from a comparer. In that case the comparer may just do a simple lexicographic comparison on the bits without any subtraction. That means they'll iterate from the most significant bit and check if any pair of bits differ, if yes then the value that has a one bit will be larger